# How to display buttons underneath each other in framelayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I have `FrameLayout` and want to add `two buttons (or more)` in this layout.
The first button shows, however when adding the second button it seems to place `it beneath the first button`. I have tried `margin top gravity` and a few others more, but **can't seem to display the button below the first one**.

Here is my XML File

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/logo1">

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dp">

<TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Distancecalc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Distance Calculator" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Distance"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Distance Calculator" />

    </FrameLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
  </TabHost>
```

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) is designed to block out an area on the screen to display `a single item`. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold `a single child view`, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and `control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child`, using the `android:layout_gravity` attribute.

Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top. The size of the FrameLayout is the size of its largest child (plus padding), visible or not (if the FrameLayout's parent permits). Views that are GONE are used for sizing only if `setConsiderGoneChildrenWhenMeasuring()` is set to true.

For your solution use a [LinearLayout with *`vertical orientation`*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) or [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/logo1">

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dp">

<TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Distancecalc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Distance Calculator" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Distance"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Distance Calculator" />

    </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```